# Unable to install libraries in R

Tags: r

I am trying to install libraries in R (like rmarkdown, shiny, dplyr, formattable etc.) and it keeps giving me error everytime. The error that I am getting is:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'cli' ...
** package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
```

Please guide me on how I can resolve this error.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is that all the output you get?  It doesn’t look like an error to me. It just looks like a message.

Comment: It wasn't letting me install any library. I ended up uninstalling and then reinstalling R and R studio.